# Program to input Name and Height and Display it. I can't figure out how to display the name and Height of the tallest person in the list

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list

```
void insertname()
{
    while (true)
    {
        char dec;
        nodename* temp;
        temp = new nodename;
        std::cout << "ENTER YOUR NAME : ";
        std::cin >> temp->name;
        std::cout << "ENTER YOUR HEIGHT : ";
        std::cin >> temp->height;
        std::cout << '\n';
        temp->next = NULL;
        if (rear == NULL)
        {
            rear = temp;
            front = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            rear->next = temp;
            rear = temp;
        }
        std::cout << "ADD ANOTHER DATA? (Y/N) : ";
        std::cin >> dec;
        std::cout << '\n';
        if (dec == 'n' || dec == 'N')
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void display()
{
    nodename* temp = front;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "--------------------------" << '\n';
        std::cout << "NAME : " << temp->name << endl;
        std::cout << showpoint << fixed << setprecision(0);
        std::cout << "HEIGHT : " << temp->height << endl;
        std::cout << showpoint << fixed << setprecision(2);
        temp = temp->next;
        std::cout << "--------------------------" << '\n';

    }
}
```

This Uses Linked List with Queue to display the name and height which I have already done but I can't figure out a way to Display the output so that it displays name and height of the tallest person from the list. I'm sorry for any errors in the program I'm relatively new to programming and im still learning. I'd Really Appreciate Help

Comment: You sort your linked list.

Comment: Initialize a `maxHeight` variable with some value such as 0. Then loop through your list and whenever the height of someone in the list is higher than `maxHeight` you store the height of that person in `maxHeight` and its name in some other variable (`tallestPerson`, for instance). After the loop you can print the values of `tallestPerson` and `maxHeight`.

Comment: While "displays name and height of the tallest person" does look like one task, it is actually two. 1) Find the tallest person. 2) Print a single node. The latter should be rather easy given your current `display()` function, so maybe you want to focus your question on how to find the tallest person?

Comment: Yes, I could go with that either my main issue is I have no idea how will i display the tallest person @JaMiT

Comment: @jinn No, your **two** main issues are that you have no idea how you will display the tallest person. As I explained, that means one main issue is that you have no idea how to find the tallest person, and the second main issue is that you have no idea how to display a person once you've found the tallest person? *Divide-and-conquer. Split problems into simpler pieces until they are so simple that you know how to solve them.*

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, what you are looking for is the STL libraries sort function, you can simply use:

`std::sort(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]), greater<int>());`

to sort any array in descending order.

Comment: The data is in a linked list, not an array. Besides, sorting methods are at least O(n lg n). Finding the tallest person in an unsorted list is O(n). Why waste time sorting?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a linked list, you can use a rolling maximum:

```
std::string name;
std::string name_tallest;
int height = 0;
int tallest_height = 0;
static const char name_prompt[] = "Enter your name:\n";
static const char height_prompt[] = "Enter your height: ";
std::cout.write(name_prompt, sizeof(name_prompt) - 1);
while (std::cin >> name)
{
    std::cout.write(height_prompt, sizeof(height_prompt) - 1);
    if (std::cin >> height)
    {
        if (height > tallest_height)
        {
            tallest_height = height;
            name_tallest = name;
        }
    }
}

std::cout << "Name of tallest person: " << name_tallest << "\n";
std::cout << "Height: " << tallest_height << "\n";
```

If you want to use a queue, then use `std::queue`.
For lists, use `std::list`.

For learning linked lists, put your linked list code into a separate file.  Prefer not to mix the linked list code with queue code or `main` code.